# Compare css selectors performance

Tags: performance, css, css-selectors

I have such code:

Html:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item"> item 1 </li>
    <li class="list-item list-item_active"> Active item </li>    
    <li class="list-item"> item 3 </li>
    <li class="list-item"> item 4 </li>
    <li class="list-item"> item 5 </li>    
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.list-item:nth-child(even) {
    background: #eee
}
.list-item_active {
    background: none;
}
```

jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/Re3xV/2/

Lets assume that `.list-item` has no child elements, which could be styled.

Problem : I need `.list-item_active` to overwrite `.list-item:nth-child(even)`

I need to determine, which of the following solutions is the fastest it terms of selector performance:

1. ul .list-item_active
2. li.list-item_active
3. .list .list-item_active
4. .list-item.list-item_active
5. .list-item_active:nth-child(n)
6. .list-item:nth-child(even):not(.list-item_active)
7. .list-item[data-state="active"] (data-state="active" should be added to html)

Probably I will use

```
.list-item_active {
    background: none !important;
}
```

as it seems not to affect performance at all (and I know that using `!important` is often a bad idea), but I still want to know, which selector is faster. Is there any automated way to make such comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), not speed. `.list-item:nth-child(even)` has higher specificity than `.list-item_active` in this case.

Change:

```
.list-item_active { ... }
```

To:

```
.list-item.list-item_active { ... }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Re3xV/3/

Comment: All selectors in the list have higher specificity, than just classname. The question is - which one of them is the fastest.

Comment: @Shtirlits: Even if they are all more specific than a single class selector, they all have different specificity values, plus one of them requires that you modify your HTML. These factors automatically render your performance question moot.

Comment: The question isn't about specificity at all. Please, read the question before writing the answer.